# Subtract column values using coalesce

Tags: sqlite

I want to subtract values in the "place" column for each record returned in a "race", "bib", "split" group by so that a "diff" column appears like so.

**Desired Output**:

```
     race | bib | split | place | diff  
     ----------------------------------
     10   | 514 | 1     | 5     | 0
     10   | 514 | 2     | 3     | 2 
     10   | 514 | 3     | 2     | 1
     10   | 17  | 1     | 8     | 0
     10   | 17  | 2     | 12    | -4
     10   | 17  | 3     | 15    | -3
```

I'm new to using the coalesce statement and the closest I have come to  the desired output is the following

```
select a.race,a.bib,a.split, a.place, 
coalesce(a.place - 
    (select b.place from ranking b where b.split < a.split), a.place) as diff
from ranking a
group by race,bib, split
```

which produces:

```
     race | bib | split | place | diff  
     ----------------------------------
     10   | 514 | 1     | 5     | 5
     10   | 514 | 2     | 3     | 2 
     10   | 514 | 3     | 2     | 1
     10   | 17  | 1     | 8     | 8
     10   | 17  | 2     | 12    | 11
     10   | 17  | 3     | 15    | 14
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

To compute the difference, you have to look up the value in the row that has the same `race` and `bib` values, and the next-smaller `split` value:

```
SELECT race, bib, split, place,
       coalesce((SELECT r2.place
                 FROM ranking AS r2
                 WHERE r2.race  = ranking.race
                   AND r2.bib   = ranling.bib
                   AND r2.split < ranking.split
                 ORDER BY r2.split DESC
                 LIMIT 1
                ) - place,
                0) AS diff
FROM ranking;
```